# Apache autoindex sub directories are smaller than the main directory when viewed on a cell phone

Tags: apache-2.4, format

I am using Xubuntu with Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server (no javascript, just html & css).
Here is my site CSS file http://ss11.sytes.net/index.css
Here is the website with the subdirectory issue: http://ss11.sytes.net/missionaries
The problem is the size of sub-directories.
When viewed on a cell phone in portrait mode, the sub-directories are smaller than the main directory. I would like them to match the size of the main directory. Any ideas?